# Has there ever been slang-dense phrasing?

Tags: slang, history

In today's culture, mainly with the rise in Gen Z kids getting online, slang in English seems to have become more fluid.

In a YouTube video from JackSepticEye, while he was reading sentences that combined Gen Z parlance, he commented that one can make whole sentences where nearly every word is slang.

> e.g. I low-key deadass yeeted my hydroflask and dabbed on the haters

Whereas in the past slang was usually a word or two, usually in response to something or an adjective.

> Rad, Cool, Grok, Dude
>
> No doubt?, You trippin?
>
> Cleaned my clock. Give me the skinny.

Has there been a time where slang was pidginned together similarly? Specifically if the majority of the sentence used English slang (so not including actual pidgin or languages like Creole languages).

Comment: Oh snap; you be trippin'. Here's the 411: back in the day peeps used hella phat slang.

Comment: You speak in slang all the time.  It's just that the slang you speak is "normal" to all the people around you.

Comment: ''I low-key deadass yeeted my hydroflask and dabbed on the haters'' Haha that's hilarious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [thieves' cant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thieves%27_cant)? Here, let me share a song:

> The Ruffin cly the nab of the Harmanbeck,
>   If we mawnd Pannam, lap, or Ruff-peck,
>   Or poplars of yarum: he cuts, bing to the Ruffmans,
>   Or els he sweares by the light-mans,
>   To put our stamps in the Harmans,
>   The ruffian cly the ghost of the Harmanbeck
>   If we heaue a booth we cly the [Jerk].

This is from *The Beggar's Curse* (1608), described by a contemporary (Dekker) as "a canting song, wherein you may learn, how this cursed generation pray, or (to speake truth) curse such officers as punish them" (see the book [Three Centuries of Canting Songs and Slang Rhymes [1536 - 1896]](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/8466/pg8466-images.html) for this and more).

A tiny bit of the barrier to understanding it is just it being old. For example, I'm sure you know the words "els" (*else*), "sweares" (*swears*), and "heaue" (*have*).

And then there's the cant, which is almost the rest of it, because the very point of cant is to obscure the meaning of what's being said:

- The Ruffin/ruffian cly [someone]: the devil take [someone] (used to wish evil on someone)
- nab: head
- [Harmanbeck](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Grose-VulgarTongue/h/harman-beck.html): a beadle
- mawnd: beg or ask
- Pannam: bread (related to Latin *panem*)
- lap: liquor (or some other drink)
- Ruff-peck: bacon
- poplars of yarum: milk pudding
- cuts: says
- bing to the Ruffmans: off to the hedges

  - the OED lists "bing" as "Slang. ? Gipsy." and not cant specifically
- light-mans: day
- stamps: legs
- [Harmans](http://www.fromoldbooks.org/Grose-VulgarTongue/h/harmans.html): the stocks

  - This and several other words use the suffix "man(s)", which is used "either as an affectionate diminutive or as a disguise device" according to the OED
- cly: take or steal
- [Jerk](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jark): a seal on a counterfeit license (the counterfeit license itself is called a "gybe" in cant)

  - While Gutenberg has this as "lerk" (starting with an *L*), this is certainly an error for either "Jerk" or "Ierk", which were just two different ways to write the same word

See also [Green's](https://books.google.com/books?id=svyKBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22off+to+the+hedges%22) (2015) and [Dekker's](https://books.google.com/books?id=9bw8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=%22stamps+in+the+Harmans%22) (1608) translations of the song.